# Need the explanation of code of string replacement using String buffer

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I got the following code from the site. But i cannot understand it clearly . Can anyone help me to understand the code. the code does the replacement of the string. It does the replacement of stringToReplace with replacement string. It is doing character replacement but i couldnot understand its detail.

```
String strIn = "Al%arm %Receipient Number% has arrived %test% is ok.";
String stringToReplace = "%Receipient Number%";
String replacementString  = "12345";
String ReplacedString = null;

int idx = strIn.lastIndexOf( stringToReplace );
if ( idx != -1 ) 
{
  StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer( strIn );
  results.replace( idx, idx+stringToReplace.length(), replacementString );
  while( (idx=strIn.lastIndexOf(stringToReplace, idx-1)) != -1 ) 
  {
    results.replace( idx, idx+stringToReplace.length(), replacementString );
  }
  //System.out.println(results.toString());
  ReplacedString = results.toString();
}
System.out.println(ReplacedString);
```

The output is

```
Al%arm 12345 has arrived %test% is ok.
```

Comment: Please check the documentation for each of the methods used here e.g. `replace`, `lastIndexOf`. That should give you an idea of how they work, and you can understand what is being done better after that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have the input string `strIn`, then the thing to replace `stringToReplace` and the replacement string `replacementString`. `ReplacedString` should be `replacedString` out of convention, by the way.

You look for the last occurrence of the string to replace with `lastIndexOf`. This gives you the last index, at which the replacement string starts in the original string.

If you found the string to replace (if the index is not -1), you use the `StringBuffer` method `replace` to replace the string from `idx` to `idx+stringToReplace.length()` (the string to replace in its entire length, starting at the found index).

You then check whether the string to replace still exists in the result, and while it does, you replace it.

You then stringify the result (a `StringBuffer`) and output it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand code is to actually debug or do a dry run. 
What i mean is that actually see the output values in the debugger to see what is a particular line doing.

In your case way to do it is to first check what each line does. 
so what does lastIndexOf in string do ? why do you think is there a check of -1 so read documentation will tell you excatly why that is happening.

Next move to replace and read document again, as to what its parameters are and what are you sending.

in any case the above code is convoluted way of doing something very simple which is

```
strIn = strIn.replaceAll(stringToReplace, replacementString)
```

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is someone has reinvented the wheel. The whole thing can be done with this line:

```
String ReplacedString = strIn.replace(stringToReplace, replacementString);
```

There is no advantage whatsoever is trying to write your own version of the `replace()` method.

Conversely, there is considerable *disadvantage* - the fact you are asking what is going on is testimony that this is hard to read and therefore bug-prone.